# Django 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable after added delete function in my views

Tags: django

I am getting this error if user isn't login and try to go admin page `'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable`. I am getting this error after added delete function in my views:

**views.py**

```
 def DeleteNotificaton(request,noti_id):
        user= request.user
        author = Blog.objects.filter(author=user)
        if user.is_authenticated and not author:
            Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,receiver=user).delete()
            Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,sender=user).delete()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Notification deleted sucessfully.')
            return redirect('notifications:notify')
        elif user.is_authenticated and  author:
             Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,receiver=user).delete()
             messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Notification deleted sucessfully.')
             return redirect('notifications:notify_author')
```

I also tried this:

```
def DeleteNotificaton(request,noti_id):
    user= request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        author = Blog.objects.filter(author=user)
        if user.is_authenticated and not author:
            Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,receiver=user).delete()
            Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,sender=user).delete()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Notification deleted sucessfully.')
            return redirect('notifications:notify')
        elif user.is_authenticated and  author:
            Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,receiver=user).delete()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Notification deleted sucessfully.')
            return redirect('notifications:notify_author')
```

getting this error `The view notifications.views.DeleteNotificaton didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` I can't access my **admin login page**.

console error:

```
ValueError: The view notifications.views.DeleteNotificaton didn't return an 

    HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
    [24/Jul/2021 04:27:54] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 500 72879
```

**update question:**
As  ihoryam said in comment section I need to be add `return redirect url` bottom of my if statement. After add it the error is gone and I can access admin login page but I am seeing `"GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0` in my console. here is my updated code:

```
def DeleteNotificaton(request,noti_id):
    user= request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        author = Blog.objects.filter(author=user)
        if not author:
            Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,receiver=user).delete()
            Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,sender=user).delete()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Notification deleted sucessfully.')
            return redirect('notifications:notify')
        if  author:
         Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,receiver=user).delete()
         messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Notification deleted sucessfully.')
         return redirect('notifications:notify_author')

  
    return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/')
```

I was getting error when only trying to go admin login page. Now I can access admin login page but how to solve console 302 error:

```
[24/Jul/2021 05:15:33] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

[24/Jul/2021 05:15:33] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2218
```

Comment: This happens because you're checking if user is authenticated `user.is_authenticated`, since user is not authenticated you won't get  into any of those if conditions and because there's no return statement after them the function returns `None`, so you should probably consider adding `return redirect('login')` or something similar at the very end

Comment: @ihoryam thanks for your comment. Do I need `return redirect` bottom of my `if user.is_authenticated` condition??

Comment: I'll try to provide you an example in answers to format the code better

Comment: I am getting this error `The view notifications.views.DeleteNotificaton didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` when trying to go admin login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a login route, and `messages` is defined somewhere above the code you've provided

```py
def DeleteNotificaton(request,noti_id):
    user= request.user
    if not user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('login')
    
    has_posts = Blog.objects.filter(author=user)
    if has_posts:
        Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,receiver=user).delete()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Notification deleted sucessfully.')
        return redirect('notifications:notify_author')
    else:
        Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,receiver=user).delete()
        Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,sender=user).delete()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Notification deleted sucessfully.')
        return redirect('notifications:notify')
```

This should do pretty much the same as the code you've provided, but will also redirect user to login page if he is not authenticated

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your code will redirect  unauthenticated user to my admin login page which I don't want. See my updated question.

Comment: and what is the desired behaviour in case user is not authenticated ?

Comment: ihoryam see my updated question. I don't want to do anything with unauthenticated user. I was getting error when trying to access admin login page. Now error is gone and seeing 302 error in my console.

Comment: 302 is not an error, it's an http status that means that a redirect has been made, see 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302

Comment: Thanks  @ihoryam for the information and I am accepting your answer

Comment: in case you don't want to do anything you can `return HttpResponse()` instead (you need to import `from django.http import HttpResponse`), this will result in 200 status code in the console, however this will also leave you with a blank webpage, since you django route won't redirect the non authenticated user to another page.
Basically this very much depends on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @ ihoryam you tried to give solution what I wanted but I make few changes in my code. you can see my updated question. If I use  `if not user.is_authenticated` logic then logout  user can't access my admin login page and they will redirected to another new page and I also don't want to redirect  unauthenticated user to my admin page. so I added `return redirect` bottom of my if statement.